# Prisma Joins: A Better Way?

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma

I am creating a Recipe App that has **Recipes as Posts** that users can comment on. There is a `recipe` Table, a `comment` Table and a `recipe_comments` Table. The `recipe_comments` Table is an associate table that contains the IDs of all Recipes and their Associated Comments.

I am trying to write a `prisma` query that can fetch me all the comments associated with a recipe. This is done by the following code:

```
const getRecipeComments = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const recipe_id = Number(req.query.recipe_id);
    const response = await prisma.recipe_comments.findMany({
      where: {
        recipe: {
          id: recipe_id,
        },
      },
      select: {
        comment_id: true,
      },
    });

    // Get Comments from IDs Collected
    const comments = response.map(async (id) => {
      const data = await prisma.comment.findMany({
        where: {
          id: id.comment_id,
        },
      });

      return data;
    });

    console.log(comments); // Promise Pending

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: "Retrieved all Recipe Comments!",
      comments, // No Data Received Here due to Promise Pending
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Please Try Again!",
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

I first run a `query` to get the Comment IDs from the `recipe_comments` table using the `recipe_id` I get from `req.params`. Then I `map()` over the `response` of this `query` and inside the `map()`, I run the `query` to fetch the comments from the `comments` table based on the `comment_id` received from the previous `response`.

There are 2 issues with this, since prisma queries are async, i get no data inside the object returned by `res.status().json()` since the `Promise` is still pending. To counter this, even if I use the `.then()` | `.catch()` approach, i get an error saying `Can't set headers after they are sent to the client`.

I doubt that my approach to do this task is wrong, can someone guide me regarding the approach i should use for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Get Comments from IDs Collected
  const comments = await Promise.all(response.map((id) => {
    const data = prisma.comment.findMany({
      where: {
        id: id.comment_id,
      },
    }).then((response) => {
      return response[0];
    }).catch((error) => {
      res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
        message: "Comments Not Found!",
        error: error.message,
      });
    });

    return data;
  }));
```

I've used `Promise.all()` to prevent `Promise ( <pending> )`. I feel like this isn't a good approach but it works. I also changed the `query` to use `.then()` | `.catch()` because nested `await` looked kinda weird. I'm open to a better solution if anyone has it.